# Launch Facebook Share Popup at Center of Screen

Tags: javascript, facebook, popup, xhtml

The following code works well and launches a facebook popup on the screen, however this popup is not centered.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fbs_click() {u=location.href;t=document.title;window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');return false;}
</script>

<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<full page url to share" onClick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank" title="Share This on Facebook"><img src="images/facebookimage.jpg" alt="facebook share"></a>
```

Here is the script that centers a popup window:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyPopUpWin(url, width, height) {
        var leftPosition, topPosition;
        //Allow for borders.
        leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
        //Allow for title and status bars.
        topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 50);
        //Open the window.
        window.open(url, "Window2",
        "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=yes,left="
        + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY="
        + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no");
    }
</script>
```

How can I update the first script so that it works in combination with the second script to result in the popup window launching in the center of the screen?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fbs_click(width, height) {
    var leftPosition, topPosition;
    //Allow for borders.
    leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
    //Allow for title and status bars.
    topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 50);
    var windowFeatures = "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=yes,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no";
    u=location.href;
    t=document.title;
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer', windowFeatures);
    return false;
}
</script>

<!-- Please change the width and height to suit your needs -->
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<full page url to share" onClick="return fbs_click(400, 300)" target="_blank" title="Share This on Facebook"><img src="images/facebookimage.jpg" alt="facebook share"></a>
```

Comment: That works absolutely perfectly! You're a super genius coder ultimate uber cool person. Thanks. :) Pia @arturhoo

Comment: for me also it is working but the problem is this code is not fetching the data and image which I need. can u please help me to fix?  I kept even <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $productDetailsArray['name_of_product']; ?>" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $productDetailsArray['product_description']; ?>" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $productDetailsArray['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $productDetailsArray['name_of_product']; ?>" title = "<?php echo $productDetailsArray['name_of_product']; ?>" />
on the header

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function fbs_click() {
      u=location.href;t=document.title;window.open(
      'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),
      'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');return false;
      }
    </script>

    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<url>" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank">Share on Facebook</a>
```

Or this post with a picture on Facebook

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function fbs_click() {
      u=location.href;t=document.title;window.open(
      'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),
      'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');return false;
      }
    </script>

    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<url>" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank"><img src="http://originus.samsung.com/us/images/support/facebook-share.png"/></a>
```

You can change the image or words 
Size pop-up window 
`width=626,height=436`
You can change the size